# Name for a part of a charity?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word like subsidiary for a charity owned and controlled by another charity? Or would the word subsidiary be used?

Comment: I can't think of anything better than subsidiary.

Comment: @JohnClifford neither could I, that's why I posted the question.

Comment: Haha, touché, my friend.

Comment: A [google search](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=subsidiary%20of%20a%20charity) for the term seems to support this; there are several pages referring to a "trading subsidiary" of a charity, though an interesting point to note is that one page states that the charity constitution must specifically provide the charity the powers to set up such a subsidiary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Branch](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/branch) is used to refer to a part of a charity:

> - A division of a business or other organization.

The Free Dictionary

- [Organisations with branch structures and the Charity Regulatory Authority](http://www.youth.ie/nyci/Organisations-branch-structures-and-Charity-Regulatory-Authority-roundtable-discussion)

> - Does your organisation have a branch type structure, with strong, well organised and operationally independent local units/committees/groups in a relationship with a national office or "HQ"?
> - The Charities Regulatory Authority requires that the trustees of all charities demonstrate that they are in control of all resources raised and managed under an organisations charity number, and that annual reports and annual accounts are complete in this regard. For organisations with branch structures as outlined above, this can pose a dilemma: should the HQ of the organisation tighten controls and produce consolidated accounts, or should the HQ encourage branches to apply for a charity number of their own, with local committee members becoming trustees in their own right, and facing the full requirements of conforming with charity law themselves?

(www.youth.ie/nyci/Organisations-branch)

Comment: Does branch still count when the other part is owned by *another* charity, Josh? I would have thought branch would imply ownership/control by the charity it's a part of.

Comment: Branches that belong to different charities may interact among them, if that is what you mean.

Comment: I was more asking if the term was still applicable when the branch is owned by a charity other then the one running it, but you've just indirectly answered the question for me anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest, ***chapter***

> : a local branch of an organization
>
> : the people in a certain area who make up one section of a large organization
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chapter)
>
> *From its origins in the world of show business, Variety often uses carnival and circus terminology. For instance, a **local or national chapter of the charity** is known as a "tent", and the main board of trustees and others of a particular tent is called the Crew. This is named after those who erected the old circus tents or nowadays provide the various technical experts to make a film or stage a live production. The chairman of the board is called the Chief Barker, after the man who drummed up customers at the fairground.* (emphasis is mine.)
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variety,_the_Children%27s_Charity)
>
> *The San Diego/Imperial Counties chapter of the American Red Cross is part of the largest and most diverse service organization in the United States. We serve more than 3.6 million people and cover nearly 10,000 square miles in the two counties.* [American Red Cross](http://www.redcross.org/ca/san-diego/about-us)
>
> *All funds donated to your local Chapter remain here to support the local Red Cross programs.* [ARC](http://www.redcross.org/local/northern-california-coastal/chapters/central-coast)
>
> [Ngram chapter leaders](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chapter+leaders&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchapter%20leaders%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: not quite what I mean.